# Injecting seperate script into HTML

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

say i have a `public/index.html` file

and then a separate html file called `otherScript` which is just a file containing `<script>` tags with a script in

how would I inject this scripts into my `public/index.html` file?

I want to use `new HtmlWebpackPlugin`

but in the example it just says:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: 'public/index.html'
  inject: true
})
```

I can't see anywhere that I  should link to the `other` html file?

Comment: Why don't you create a JavaScript file instead?

Comment: because it's a script inside the tags..

Comment: There is no way to do that using webpack, specially with html-webpack-plugin. The property inject refeers to injecting all the scripts created by webpack into that html you refeered on the template property.

Comment: *"because it's in script tags"* is not relevant.  It shouldn't be.  Fix the actual problem and you'll be able to include the script with no issues.

Comment: @Archer what do you mean? It's in script tags because it's a newrelic script that needs injecting into my html file but i don't want to put it in the initial html. so how do I do this?

Comment: You remove the script tags, change the file extension to `.js` and include it with a script tag in the html file.

Comment: so I don't use webpack at all? I need to though coz the script may sometimes not be needed

Comment: This really sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  I suggest you take a few steps back and start at the beginning.  If you're having to try and force files with script tags into html files then you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @Archer ok but if you don't think webpack can inject scripts in then I think you've not come across that part before because it can totally do that. I'm just not sure how, hence why I came here

Comment: https://github.com/petehunt/webpack-howto/issues/46 as people have mentioned here, very much possible. but solution is hard to find

Comment: I'm not saying it can't.  You're saying you want to inject a html file with script tags and javascript in it.  That is wrong.  Fix that and your problem goes away.

Comment: ok sure. lets say it's a JS file. and I import it in a script tag, that's leaving webpack out...I need it to be in webpack so I can conditionally include it or not

Comment: also importing it as a script seemed to fail and when I view the file in the browser it seems to think it's a html file even when I remove all the js?

Comment: @Archer when I import the file as a JS file into my html script tag I get this error: `Unexpected token <` and it's pointing to the first line: `<!doctype html>` but that doctype syntax doesn't appear anywhere in my js file that I'm importing?

Answer (score 2):

If it's an HTML file, you can load it using a Webpack loader called [**raw-loader**](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/raw-loader/) or you could use [**html-loader**](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/html-loader/).

And use it like this:

**Webpack.config**

```
{
  test: /\.html$/,
  use: 'raw-loader'
}
```

**Module**

```
// import file

import htmlFile from 'myfile.html';

// insert the contents of file at end of body

var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', htmlFile);
```

However, an HTML file full of script tags sounds like bad practice IMO.

If you want to inject the scripts to the page, I would suggest using a different method entirely.

One way would be to import the scripts as normal using `import` or `require`, or you could have an array of dependencies to load and load them all like this:

```
var dependencies = [
    'path/to/script/1.js',
    'path/to/script/2.js'
]

for(var i = 0; i < dependencies.length; i++) {
    let script = document.createElement('script');
     script.type = 'text/javascript';
     script.src = dependencies[i];
     document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`html-webpack-tags-plugin`](https://github.com/jharris4/html-webpack-tags-plugin) plugin.

This is helpful if you want to enable cache busting on the script, which was the main reason I didn't want to just use the `copy-webpack-plugin` and a static script element.

**webpack.dev.config.js**

```
new HtmlWebpackTagsPlugin({
  // this script must be loaded before all other scripts
  append: false,
  tags: ['src/myScript.js'],
}),
```

**webpack.prod.config.js**

```
new HtmlWebpackTagsPlugin({
  // this script must be loaded before all other scripts
  append: false,
  tags: ['src/myScript.js'],
  useHash: true,
  addHash: (assetPath, hash) => {
    const parts = assetPath.split('.');
    parts[parts.length - 1] = `${hash}.${parts[parts.length - 1]}`;
    return parts.join('.');
  },  
}),
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that using webpack, specially with html-webpack-plugin. The property inject refeers to injecting all the scripts created by webpack into that html you refeered on the template property.

Comment: im sure you can inject scripts in. you're saying there is absolutely no way to inject code into the html file?

Comment: Using pure webpack, without manually touching the html, no you cant.

Comment: You could do what martin has answered, which is a valid way. But i guess it is not how you want to do

Comment: when I import the file as a JS file into my html script tag I get this error: `Unexpected token <` and it's pointing to the first line: `<!doctype html>` but that doctype syntax doesn't appear anywhere in my js file that importing?

Comment: show us an example on how your js file looks like and how you are importing on html.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can do this. I made some example, hope it will help you.

**In webpack js:**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const TerserPluign = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    index: './src/assets/js/index.js',
    about: './src/assets/js/about.js'
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './build'),
    // publicPath: 'my-domain/'
  },
  mode: 'none',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png)$/,
        type: 'asset',
        parser: {
          dataUrlCondition: {
            maxSize: 60 * 1024 // max size 60 kilobytes.
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.txt/,
        type: 'asset/source',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(less)$/,
        use: [
          // 'style-loader', 'css-loader', 'less-loader'
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'less-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [ '@babel/env'],
            plugins: [ '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties']
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.hbs$/,
        use: [
          'handlebars-loader'
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'),
        'global': {},
    }),
    new TerserPluign(), // To use reduce size of bundle files,
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].[contenthash].css"
    }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin({
      cleanOnceBeforeBuildPatterns: [
        '**/*',
        path.join(process.cwd(), 'dummyBuildFolder/**/*')
      ]
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Default HTML',
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: 'src/templates/index.hbs',
      description: 'this is meta description for index page',
      chunks: ['index']
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'About Us HTML',
      filename: 'about.html',
      template: 'src/templates/about.hbs',
      description: 'this is meta description for about us page',
      chunks: ['about']
    })
  ]
}
```

Above will generate two files, **index.html** and **about.html**

**In index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Default HTML</title>
    <meta name="description" content="this is meta description for index page" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script defer src="index.22a0682faed73cf496ac.js"></script>
    <link href="index.2ab526c55a3c67e01bfb.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="my_root" />
    <div id="initialMessage"></div>
    <div id="lipsumTxtId"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In **about.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>About Us HTML</title>
    <meta name="description" content="this is meta description for about us page" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script defer src="about.0d3ba2ce20763dbd16dc.js"></script>
    <link href="about.352d245e3219b89be11d.css" rel="stylesheet"></head>
  <body />
</html>
```